# Can someone explain what the difference is in the p value of the summary output and emmeans (pairwise, least square means)?

Tags: anova, descriptive-statistics, marginal-distribution

I have a model:

`m_ramet<-glmer(ramets_net ~ salt * typhagroup + ramets_start +
            (1|site),data=morphdata, family="poisson"(link="log"))`

and am running some statistics to see whether the interaction between "salt" and "typhagroup" is significant. Therefore I've used the summary function and Anova (type III) function in the car package to investigate this model:

`Anova(m_ramet, contrasts=list(topic=contr.sum, sys=contr.sum), type="III")
summary(m_ramet)`

I have a significant interaction, therefore I am looking at which typhagroup means differ significantly from each other in the different salt treatments. So I use the emmeans function in emmeans package: 
`emmeans(m_ramet, list(pairwise ~ typhagroup*salt), adjust = "tukey")`

I'm just wondering how the p values calculated between the 3 functions differ. For instance, if I make "salt" and "typhagroup" factors with the different levels, I end up getting a p value for each of the levels using just the summary function, but these are different from the emmeans p values comparing the same groups. Can anyone clarify how these p values are calculated?

Thanks.

Comment: The model is $Y=\beta_0 +\beta_1 X_1 +...+\beta_k X_k+ \gamma Z +\epsilon$. All of these null hypothesis are in the form $l_0\beta_0 + l_1 \beta_1 +...+l_k\beta_k = 0$ or $L\beta =0$. You got three different p values means you used three different $L$. If you really want to undersand where the difference p values come from, try to find their corresponding $L$.